# Routing not working in angularJS getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am using nodeJS as the middleware and using angularJS in the UI and for routing. This is a SPA application but currently routing is not working getting 404 error while trying to load template.

The application folder structure is as below:

[image: Folder structure]

Below code is used for routing:

```
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/addStudent', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/addStudent.html',
    }).
    when('/viewStudent', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/viewStudent.html',
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '#'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: We have no idea how your server routes are set up. SHouldn't the templates be in your `public` directory?

Comment: I have moved the template folder to the public and updated the path. Now its working. Thanks.